# webpage is receiving css file but not implementing it

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, elixir

I am making a react webpage that is hosted from flask and called through elixir. When I try to call my webpage. The react html loads, but non of the css is displayed. According to chromes web developer tool my css file is loaded and returns HTTP status code 200. Also when I preview the content of the css file I can see that all the css code is there. Its just not implementing the code into the html page.

my html page that react is loaded into

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="time-period/static/css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

chrome inspect tool network tab

[image]

**UPDATE**

I just found in the google chrome console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3005/time-period/static/css/main.css".
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3005/time-period/static/css/main.fd12a70d.css".
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing my css to not be implemented into the html and how I should try to fix it?

Comment: hover over main.css and say what that url is?

Comment: Are you trying to style your react components with css?

Comment: when I hover over the main.css it says `http://localhost:3005/time-period/static/css/main.css` and yes I'm trying to style my react component with css

Comment: and you're serving your webpage over `http://localhost:3005/` as well?

Comment: yes. `http://localhost:3005 ` goes to the Elixir which proxies to the flash server that's hosted at `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: The fact that the file loads to the browser make me confident that the flask server and Elixir are working properly. I'm assuming that I'm calling the css file improperly.

Comment: Why not just bring in your CSS using an import statement in your JS?

Comment: I already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that the css is being called incorrectly, but that Elixir is not separating the css from the html body when it gets it from flask. When it returns the webpage by default it makes the whole page `text/html`. That's why the file is returned with status code 200, but isn't implemented. You need to edit the Elixir return header to fix this. The answer will look similar to this. This code will go into the body of the code it receives from the flask server and separate the meta-data from the rest of the code so the css is return as `type="text/css"`

```
headers_kwlist = Enum.map(example.headers, fn { a, b } -> {String.to_atom(a), b} end)
conn
|> put_resp_content_type(headers_kwlist[:"Content-Type"])
|> html(example.body)
```